# issue with selecting radio button in perl

Tags: perl

I have a html,

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="number_type" VALUE="0" CHECKED>ABC<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="number_type" VALUE="1" >DEF<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="number_type" VALUE="2" >GHI<BR><BR>
```

And I need to write a perl code which selects second radio button.

This is my current code,

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech=>get("someurl.com");
$mech->set_fields('number_type' => "1");
```

But when I execute this code, I get following errors,

4 elements found for input with name 'number_type'

I am new to perl and I am clueless as to how to go about selecting second radio button.

Kindly help,
Thanks in advance,
Rashmi

Comment: It seems that `radio` fields are not supported http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=952072

Answer (score -1):

```
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        number_type => 1,
    },
);
```